# OpenMesh: fast search of common neighbor vertices

Tags: c++, c++11, openmesh

I have a function which finds the common neighbors of two vertices `v1` and `v2`, i.e. those vertices that are connected to both  `v1` and `v2`:

```
std::vector<MyMesh::VertexHandle> find_common_neighbors(MyMesh & mesh, MyMesh::VertexHandle & v1, MyMesh::VertexHandle & v2){
    std::vector<MyMesh::VertexHandle> common_neighbors;

    //iterate over neighbors of v1
    for(MyMesh::VertexVertexIter it1 = mesh.vv_iter(v1); it1.is_valid(); ++it1) {
      //neighbors of v2
      for(MyMesh::VertexVertexIter it2 = mesh.vv_iter(v2); it2.is_valid(); ++it2) {
        if ((*it1)==(*it2)){
            common_neighbors.push_back(*it1);     
        }
      }
    }
    return common_neighbors;
```

The function simply iterates over the neighborhood of `v1` and `v2` and checks if finds any vertex that appears in both neighborhoods. Unfortunately, this function seems to be the bottleneck of my code, thus my question is whether there is a more optimal way to accomplish this in OpenMesh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not an expert on OpenMesh proper, but it looks like you are using a rather efficient Circulator to find these pairs of vertices.

The only obvious problem with your function is the fact you are allocating and returning the `std::vector` object.

The declaration

`std::vector<MyMesh::VertexHandle> common_neighbors;`

defines an empty vector (and subsequent `push_back`s internally call `malloc` which is unpredictably expensive). The least you can do here is preallocate the approximate expected amount of vertices.

If you are calling this function for a large (10000+ ?) number of distinct `v1, v2` pairs, you should change the signature of your function to

```
std::vector<MyMesh::VertexHandle> find_common_neighbors(MyMesh & mesh,
               MyMesh::VertexHandle & v1, MyMesh::VertexHandle & v2,
               std::vector<MyMesh::VertexHandle>& common_neighbors);
```

and pass preallocated `common_neighbors` there.

You should probably also give more context (how do you call this function, what do you actually do with these vertices - e.g., if you need a `v3` adjacent to both `v1` and `v2` and then make a triangular face `(v1,v2,v3)`, then probably you should just take a `v1-v2` edge and iterate over adjacent triangles...) so that more optimization can be provided.

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer! v1 and v2 are never directly connected, the typical size of common_neighbors is the order of 10 and I need the function to identify topological features (such as wedges or cracks) in the mesh. I will try to change the signature as you suggested if you think malloc is still important for such small vectors.

Comment: Usually malloc is really important, because the workload is small. Internally it may call some global OS function which uses locks and so sometimes it can block your thread for an indefinite period.

Answer (score 1):

Another aspect to consider is that you have a nested loop. Assuming *common_neighbors* is the order of 10, then both v1 and v2 have **at least 10** neighbors. By using an `unordered_map`, we can solve this with two separate loops - which means 20 iterations instead of 100 iterations. More precisely O(n1 + n2) instead of O(n1*n2).

```
std::vector<MyMesh::VertexHandle> find_common_neighbors(MyMesh & mesh, MyMesh::VertexHandle & v1, MyMesh::VertexHandle & v2)
{
    std::vector<MyMesh::VertexHandle> common_neighbors;
    std::unordered_map<MyMesh::VertexHandle, bool> candidates;

    for(MyMesh::VertexVertexIter it = mesh.vv_iter(v1); it.is_valid(); ++it) {
        candidates[*it] = true;
    }

    for(MyMesh::VertexVertexIter it = mesh.vv_iter(v2); it2.is_valid(); ++it) {
        if (candidates.find(*it) != candidates.end()) 
            common_neighbors.push_back(*it); 
    }

    return common_neighbors;
}
```

**Details**

To understand what we are doing here, let's first consider a conceptionally similar approach that uses `std::vector<MyMesh::VertexHandle> candidates`:

- 1st loop: add all neighbors of *v1* to *candidates*
- 2nd loop: if a neighbor of *v2* is *found* in *candidates*, add it to *common_neighbors*

However, *find* on a vector is inefficient (same as iterating the candidates vector each time). This is why we replace the candidate vector with an `unordered_map`, which is a hash map with an average complexity of O(1) (worst case is O(n) - but practically speaking, we can assume it to be O(1)).

**Step up**

If it makes sense (and is practicle) to group your calls to `find_common_neighbors`, such that: `...MyMesh::VertexHandle & v1, std:vector<MyMesh::VertexHandle> & v2)` - then, note that the 1st loop (populating the candidates map) can be reused for all elements in v2. So we get O(n1 + m * n2) instead of O(m * (n1 + n2)), where n1 is size of v1, n2 is average size in v2 and m is number of vertices in v2.